# How to create geometric shapes in R?

Tags: r

I want to plot some geometrical shapes but I dont know what values to put in a vector so they can be plotted. How do you know what numbers should be inserted in a vector so they can create certain shapes?

Can you provide a few shapes such circle, triangle, etc?

More importantly is to explain how to be able to know what numbers to use.

Comment: Perhaps this paper: ["R Package shape: functions for plotting graphical shapes, colors..."](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shape/vignettes/shape.pdf) might be of some use.

Comment: Actually i am talking about the hard way of doing it,with vectors, without the use of packages.

Comment: Hopefully others can advise as I have no experience in R =)